# View Big5 File in Text Editor

Tags: software-rec, text-editors, encoding, character-encoding

I have a file encoded in Chinese Big5.
Is there a text editor that I can use to view the file in Chinese?

I'm on Windows. If I view the file in Notepad++ I see it decoded with my 8bit locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### vim

The text editor vim supports Big5 encoding. You will also need to set vim to use a font that includes the set of characters needed.

Vim commands for encodings include

```
:e ++enc=big5           (reload current file using big5 encoding)
:set enc=big5
:set fenc=big5
```

### notepad++

From http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/the-latest-version-5.6.8.html

> Notepad++ v5.6 new features and fixed bugs (from v5.5.1)
>   Add languages encoding - **Chinese traditional (BIG5)**, Chinese Simplified (GB2312), Japanese (Shift JIS), Korean (EUC), Thai (TIS-620), Hebrew (iso-8859-8), Hebrew (1255), Central European (1250), Cyrillic (1251), Cyrillic (KOI8-U), Cyrillic (KOI8-R), Cyrillic (Mac), Western European(1252), Greek (1253), Turkish(1254), Arabic (1256), Baltic (1257), Vietnamese (1258), ISO_8859-1 to ISO_8859-16 and a lot of more.

update:

[image: Selecting Big5 encoding]
[image: Choosing a suitable font]

Comment: I've poked through all the settings in Notepad++ and I can't find a setting to view as Big5. I ended up opening the file in Chrome and changing the view encoding to Big5 to read the file.

Comment: @OregonTrail: See updated answer

Comment: Awesome, thanks for screenshot. Turns out I just had an old version of NP++ installed.